# I have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1) Error everytime I switch UIViews exactly 12 times in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a problem with an EXC_BAD_ACESS error for Swift 3, and it happens after I switch UIViewControllers EXACTLY 12 times. It works perfectly fine the previous 11 times. When I do get the error, it highlights **level03.prepareToPlay()** in red.

When I comment it out, it shows **level04.prepareToPlay()** in red. Note that **level01.prepareToPlay()** and **level02.prepareToPlay()** is always good and does not cause errors. When I comment out the ones that work, it still gives me errors for level03 and ones after that. What can I do? I provided my code below:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

var timer01 = Timer()
var currentTime = 0.00
var score = 0
var inAir = false
var currentLevel = 1

var minimumTime3 = 2.49
var maximumTime3 = 3.50

var minimumTime4 = 3.49
var maximumTime4 = 4.50

var minimumTime5 = 4.49
var maximumTime5 = 5.50

var minimumTime6 = 5.49
var maximumTime6 = 6.50


var aww = AVAudioPlayer()
var tempoEnd = AVAudioPlayer()
var musicEnd = AVAudioPlayer()
var tempoEnd2 = AVAudioPlayer()
var musicEnd2 = AVAudioPlayer()
var tempoEnd3 = AVAudioPlayer()
var musicEnd3 = AVAudioPlayer()
var tempoEnd4 = AVAudioPlayer()
var musicEnd4 = AVAudioPlayer()
var songEnd = AVAudioPlayer()
var songEnd2 = AVAudioPlayer()
var songEnd3 = AVAudioPlayer()
var songEnd4 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level01 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level02 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level03 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level04 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level05 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level06 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level07 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level08 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level09 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level10 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level11 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level12 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level13 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level14 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level15 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level16 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level17 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level18 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level19 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level20 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level21 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level22 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level23 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level24 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level25 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level26 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level27 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level28 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level29 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level30 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level31 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level32 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level33 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level34 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level35 = AVAudioPlayer()
var level36 = AVAudioPlayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let audioPath01 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Level01", ofType: "mp3")
    do{
        try level01 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath01!))
    } catch {
        //error
    }
    level01.prepareToPlay()

    let audioPath02 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Level02", ofType: "mp3")
    do{
        try level02 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath02!))
    } catch {
        //error
    }
    level02.prepareToPlay()
    let audioPath03 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Level03", ofType: "mp3")
    do{
        try level03 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath03!))
    } catch {
        //error
    }
    level03.prepareToPlay()

    let audioPath04 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Level04", ofType: "mp3")
    do{
        try level04 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath04!))
    } catch {
        //error
    }
    level04.prepareToPlay()
```

Comment: How are you "switching views"?

Comment: I am using 2 buttons and I controlled dragged to the viewcontroller I wanted to display by selecting the "show" option in the main storyboard.

Comment: It sounds like you are creating an every-deeper stack of modal view controllers and running out of memory. You should search for informstion on unwind segues or possibly you could use a tab bar controller

Comment: If they are globals then you will only have a single instance of each, but you probably still need to look at how your navigation is structured to avoid a deep stack of view controllers